# How Can I get the location of a user app from another user of same app

Tags: python, django, flutter, dart

I’m trying to build a simple pick up and delivery app. I want a user to submit a pickup location and delivery location.

Then as soon as the user submits I want to be able to get the locations of the riders’ apps but I don’t know how to go about it. It’s just like a normal for example uber app that searches the drivers locations and calculates the nearest one.

Calculating the nearest one is not the issue as I can do that with google maps api, but how can I get the riders app location from the backend.? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a good plugin that does a lot of the heavy lifting here:
https://pub.dev/packages/location

The nice thing about this plugin is that it handles a lot of the permission stuff for you. (although you still have to add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to the Info.plist for iOS)

If, then, you want to read data from Device A on Device B, the data flowpath would look like this:
- Device A gets own location
- Device A uploads location to database (such as firebase)
- Device B queries, or directly receives data from firebase
- Device B reads location data from Device A.

I would recommend using firebase for this transfer, since it's free to get it off the ground.  A good place to start would be here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9uVcubnVfc

Comment: Thank you for the response. But how can I remotely use this app? After going through the plugins details I can request within the app, what about requesting from the backend?

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand completely what needs to be done.